# How many I/O pins does this device have?

Tags: fpga, output, input

[Digilent Online Store Page](https://store.digilentinc.com/basys-3-artix-7-fpga-trainer-board-recommended-for-introductory-users/) I have attached a link to the digilent store webpage of an FPGA board where the datasheet and schematic can be viewed in PDF's.

I want to know how many free digital I/O pins I have to connect to external devices to not counting the I/O already used for the on board switches, buttons, LED's etc.

I'm guessing its the 4 Pmod connectors leaving me 40 pins to use?

Comment: Would have been a better idea to leave a link to the datasheet rather than an image of the key features

Comment: @MCG Ok, I have edited and added a link to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each pmod has 12 pins: 8 IO, 2 power, and 2 ground. So four pmods means 32 IO pins in total.

Comment: Ah right ok, there are 2 power and 2 ground pins on every pmod connector. Thanks